# lodash function to return the result of .tap

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm looking for a lodash (or underscore) function that will return the result of `.tap`.

I want something like this:

```
var run = function(collection, fn) {
  return fn(collection);
};

_.mixin({run: run});
```

I'm hoping I've overlooked something in the docs so I don't have to create my own mixin.

Comment: Is the point of this for chaining?

Comment: I'd like to keep it in the chain so I can `.filter('piece').run(function(n){return n.length > 2;}).value()`. `.tap` is the closest I could find.

Comment: `tap` is specifically designed to **not** modify the chain, perhaps you're looking for `map`.

Comment: It's now available in lodash with [thru](https://lodash.com/docs#thru)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic mixin like this:

```
function add(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c
}

function sub(a, b, c) {
  return a - b - c
}

_.mixin({
  run: function (v, f) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2)
    args.unshift(v)
    return f.apply(this, args)
  }
})
var r = _.chain(1).run(add, 1, 1).run(sub, 2, 2).value()

console.log(r) ->  -1
1 + 1 + 1 - 2 - 2 = -1
```

You can pass function and additional parameter. The function will be called with the result from the last chain operation as first parameter and the additional parameter from the `run` call.

Answer (score 0):

In lodash, you can use [`_.thru`](https://lodash.com/docs#thru) since v3:

> ```
> _.thru(value, interceptor, [thisArg])
> ```
>
> This method is like `_.tap` except that it returns the result of interceptor.